# Swift Package minimum ios version

Tags: swift, ios9, swift-package-manager

I've created my package which I would like to use in my projects. In the package, I'm using UIStackView. When I adding the package to the project and running it I get errors **'UIStackView' is only available in iOS 9.0 or newer**. 
Why I get this error if my project iOS target sitting set to 9.0? How can I solve this problem without making iOS 8 support in the package?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/package the `.platform` in the sample doc? Then check the "Declaring Supported Platforms" parts.

Answer (score 8):

Supported platforms and their versions can be added by `platforms` parameter of `Package` initializer inside the Package.swift file:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "Package Name",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v13)]
    // ...
)
```

Answer (score 2):

UIStackView introduced in iOS 9 so if your project supports iOS 8 too then UIStackView will be not available for iOS 8. So add check like below

```
if #available(iOS 9, *) {
         //UIStackView code
} else {
         // any other alternative 
}
```

Comment: My project support 9.0+. Where in package I can set 9.0+ as well?